# IceCast2 (2.4.1) rotation and live

Tags: icecast

I have a Icecast2 (2.4.1) setup working, users connect to /live and listens to my rotation. Now I want to have another "mount point" so I can go live and back to rotation.

I haven't found a guide or help I could understand so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for are "fallbacks".
The [documentation describes them](http://icecast.org/docs/icecast-2.4.1/config-file.html#mountsettings).

Basically you would have a transition like this:

```
/live.ogg
 ↓ (↑)
/rotation.ogg
```

If /live.ogg disconnects, all listeners are transferred to /rotation.ogg.
 New listeners connecting to /live.ogg are directly served the /rotation.ogg stream.

*If* fallback-override is set, then the arrow in brackets becomes relevant:
If /live.ogg reconnects, all listeners are transferred back from /rotation.ogg to /live.ogg.
*Otherwise* all listeners remain on /rotation.ogg and only new listeners are served /live.ogg.

In terms of config it would look something like this (only relevant parts are included):

```
<mount>
  <mount-name>/live.ogg</mount-name>
  <fallback-mount>/rotation.ogg</fallback-mount>
  <fallback-override>1</fallback-override>
</mount>
<mount>
  <mount-name>/rotation.ogg</mount-name>
</mount>
```

Comment: Working perfect, I begin to understand how this works. My next task would be, if possible, to prevent silence, maybe a jingle when I go live and fading between. Maybe you can help? If not, it's okay, you've been to a lot of help allready :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to address there. Fallback transitions themselves have no cross-fade, they are a hard cut over between streams. The best you can do is to vaguely match volume and mood between both. Each listener will also transition at a slightly different time, as there is a natural drift. Also between the actual transition and the listener hearing it there can be a considerable delay due to the *client* side buffer.